# Bypass Cross Origin to Fetch Webpage with Javascript by Loading into Img Tag

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to bypass cross origin by loading the external url into an image tag, would this sort of thing work?!

algo:

1. create element img
2. img src = external html webpage
3. img.onload on the new img to load the link.
4. get the contents of the image
5. parse html

Would it throw errors that the image is not valid etc.?

Comment: No. That is not possible - Did you try and look in the console? `Blocked current origin from receiving cross-site document at ... with MIME type text/html.`

Comment: Have you tried using YQL?

Comment: why would you even want to do this? node and phantomjs are both free, use those.